# Marshaling unmanaged dll in C# through ComInterop without registering DLL

Tags: c#, marshalling, com-interop, unmanaged

I have an unmanaged DLL which I'm currently calling from C# using a COM Class Wrapper.

```
[ComImport(), Guid("75E81043-CAD5-11D3-800D-00105A5E2FA0")]
public class MyObject { }

[ComImport(), Guid("75E81042-CAD5-11D3-800D-00105A5E2FA0"),
 InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface MyInterface
{
    string EncryptString([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string bstrOrginal);    
}
```

Then to call:

```
MyInterface obj = (MyInterface)new MyObject();
string crypt = obj.EncryptString("something");
```

This works, the return value is as I expect. However, it requires that the dll is registered with regsvr32.

I'm looking for a way to do this without the requirement of needing to regsvr32. Preferably, by just having a copy of the dll available. It is worth noting, I have the source for the unmanaged dll, and the ability to modify it if necessary.

A shove in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this might help:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694515(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have a lot of reading to do, but I will give this a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have wanted to do the same thing myself. As Jim mentions it is possible to get the address of `DllRegisterServer` and call it, but that still modifies your registry with the various entries. If you don't want to do this (for example, you might not have the necessary privileges to write to the Registry), then there is another way.

Any DLL that houses one or more in-process COM objects must expose the `DllGetClassObject` function. This function is used to acquire an instance of the COM class factory that is used to create a COM object. What you need to do is:

1. Load the library (DLL) that houses the desired COM object
2. Locate the `DllGetClassObject` function
3. Call `DllGetClassObject`, passing it the CLSID of the desired COM object, this will return an `IClassFactory` instance.
4. Call the `CreateInstance` method on the class factory to get an instance of the COM object.
5. Cast the returned object to the interface you wish to use.

Note that there be dragons with this approach -- it is fairly low level. If you get anything wrong you will experience access violation exceptions or worse. (For instance, your interface declaration has to exactly match the COM interface).

I have included some sample code at [gist](https://gist.github.com/1568627) which you might like to use if you want to go this way.

Using this code would look something like this:

```
// Load the library. You dispose this after you are finished with
// all of your COM objects. 
var library = new LibraryModule();
library.Load("mylibrary.dll"); or whatever your dll is called

var clsid = new Guid("75E81043-CAD5-11D3-800D-00105A5E2FA0");

var myObject = (MyInterface)ComHelper.CreateInstance(library, clsid);
```

Just note that if you dispose of the `LibraryModule` object, then this will unload the DLL. Depending on your needs, you might just assign the value to a static field so that it exists for the lifetime of the program.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the very interesting solution. However, when I tried to use your code, it fails saying that DllGetClassObject does not exist in the loaded dll. The dll I loaded is a .net 4 assembly with "Register for COM interop" checked and using the proper (I guess) attributes for interfaces and classes. Could you please help?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up your unmanaged DLL for registration-free COM. There's a pretty complete [walkthrough here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx), with plenty of examples. Among other things, it involves using manifests to point to the file, side-by-side assemblies, and some interop.

An important note in the walkthrough is that registration is required for the initial setup of the client, but not later.

Answer (score 1):

If your DLL has to be a COM object, then it must be registered. This registration does not need to be performed by regsvr32. All regsvr32 does is load the DLL, get the address of DllRegisterServer and call it it. DllRegisterServer adds the necessary entries to the registry for an application to use the object.

If your DLL does not need to be a COM object, you can modify it to simply export the function(s) you need and p-invoke it(them).

Comment: The PInvoke method would be great, except that the dll api is not nearly as simple as my example. My issue was more with that it has to be registered by an external method... Boo's suggestion may be the way I end up going.

Comment: Not quite accurate. There is such a thing as [registration free COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx), which might be intended for just this.